# PHPmailier delivered as spam

Tags: phpmailer, spam-prevention, self-hosting, zoho

I am hosting my own website instead of using a regular paid webhost and use PHPmailer to send out notices to my users.  I want to keep my mail from going to their spam folder.  I am using my internet host as my SMTP to send the mail and ZOHOmail to receive the mail.

Here is the code to send the mail:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp-server.tampabay.rr.com';    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '******@tampabay.rr.com';   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                   // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->From = 'webmaster@picknflgames.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Pick NFL Games';
$mail->addReplyTo('webmaster@picknflgames.com');
//$mail->addReturnPath('webmaster@picknflgames.com');

//  $mail->addAddress('webmaster@picknflgames.com');               // Name is optional
//  $mail->addCC('$TE');
//  $mail->addBCC($value);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to     50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

I read where I could enable SPF, but I am not sure if that can be done with my internet hose email.  Maybe I should try using ZOHOmail to send.

Here are the headers from a recent email:

```
From:   Pick NFL Games <webmaster@picknflgames.com>
Subject:    Season is fast approaching
Date:   August 27, 2015 11:30:35 PM EDT
To:     Patrick Lewis <patrick@patricklewis.net>
Reply-To:   webmaster@picknflgames.com
Delivered-To:   patrick@patricklewis.net
Received-Spf:   Pass (zoho.com: domain of webmaster@picknflgames.com designates 173.169.21.54 as permitted sender using best guess )  client-ip: 173.169.21.54
Return-Path:    <webmaster@picknflgames.com>
Return-Path:    <webmaster@picknflgames.com>
Received:   from cdptpa-oedge-vip.email.rr.com (cdptpa-outbound-snat.email.rr.com [107.14.166.226]) by mx.zohomail.com with SMTP id 144073263762811.694320566534088; Thu, 27 Aug 2015 20:30:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received:   from [173.169.21.54] ([173.169.21.54:32798] helo=10.0.1.99) by cdptpa-oedge03 (envelope-from <webmaster@picknflgames.com>) (ecelerity 3.5.0.35861 r(Momo-dev:tip)) with ESMTP id E9/20-20019-CD5DFD55; Fri, 28 Aug 2015 03:30:36 +0000
Message-Id:     <a0634c40fd39d8be6126636437ceda96@10.0.1.99>
X-Priority:     3
X-Mailer:   PHPMailer 5.2.8 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
Mime-Version:   1.0
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding:  8bit
X-Rr-Connecting-Ip:     107.14.168.142:25
X-Cloudmark-Score:  0
X-Zohomail:     ZRCVF-BYFANCY_1 SS_1 SFPD SFPP UW11 SFP_WHTCNT_EXT  SGR4_1_11085_176
X-Zohomail-Owner:   <a0634c40fd39d8be6126636437ceda96@10.0.1.99>+zmo_1_<webmaster@picknflgames.com>
X-Zohomail-Sender:  173.169.21.54
X-Zoho-Virus-Status:    2
```

Comment: Update your PHPMailer - you're using an old version.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use well-known SMTP server to solve such issues. You can use gmail for example (it allows you to send emails via SMTP/SSL), but if you want to send emails from your host you should do the followign things to make sure your host is not treated as spam host:

- Make sure your host is not open relay: i.e. anonymous can't conntect to its 25 port and send anything to anyone (there are open relay check engines over the Internet, use them)
- Have some meaningful reverse DNS record. Your IP should resolve to something like `mx.<YOUR_EMAIL_DOMAIN>`, not `44.33.22.191.clients-dsl.my.local.isp.net`
- Use SPF: you should have `v=spf1 YOUR_HOST_IP` record for your email domain (`YOUR_EMAIL_DOMAIN`)

These 3 steps increase your chances to send emails from `some_user@YOUR_EMAIL_DOMAIN` with out of getting into "spam" folder.

How ever, antispam policy is not always clear, so there is no 100% guarantee